# How do I compile multiple cpp files into a single executable using g++ when the files are interdependent?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm making a calculator in c++ that accepts extremely high values. I made a class for the numbers, which I've defined in a header. My first cpp file contains basic functions like add, subtract, multiply, and divide [(link)](https://github.com/eindacor/utilities/blob/master/bignum_funcdefs.cpp). My second cpp file contains class definitions, which allow me to manipulate the number objects as needed [(link)](https://github.com/eindacor/utilities/blob/master/bignum_classdefs.cpp). My third cpp file is the main, which doesn't have much yet [(link)](https://github.com/eindacor/utilities/blob/master/main.cpp). I'm trying to link these files together using:

```
g++ -o bignumbers bignum_funcdefs.cpp bignum_classdefs.cpp main.cpp
```

From what I've read, passing multiple files through g++ in this fashion is no different than passing them one at a time. Obviously the problem is that bignum_classdefs.cpp needs the functions from bignum_funcdefs.cpp, but I don't know how to make them accessible. I also tried this:

```
g++ -c bignum_funcdefs.cpp
g++ -c bignum_classdefs.cpp bignum_funcdefs.o
```

But this gives me the same errors that the functions in funcdefs haven't been defined. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a way to make these files work the way they are? Is there a better way to structure my cpp files, classes, and headers? The entire repo can be found [here](https://github.com/eindacor/utilities), any advice is much appreciated. Specific suggestions using my code would help even more.

Comment: Gives you what error exactly? No paraphrasing please. It isn't clear from your description whether you're getting compilation errors or linker errors. NB nobody is going to download your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate your class definition and your implementation.  Put the design of the class in a `.h` file and include it in both cpp files.  This is the typical pattern for scaling projects beyond a single file.

Also declare (but not implement) any functions that are in one file and called by the other in the `.h` file.  This typically looks like:

```
extern bignum addNumbers(bigNumber &, bigNumber &) ;
```

I see you have a `.h` for your class, so just add all declarations for the functions from `bignum_funcdefs.cpp` into the bottom of `bignum_decs.h`

Comment: When I sit down with the code again I'll try this. But before I do, should I read up on how `extern` works? Is that essential to what you're describing? Also, if I'm adding declarations for the functions in the header file, wouldn't this mean that those functions are being declared in two different places? I'm not questioning what you said, just trying to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: The extern is old "C" magic that says the implementation doesn't live here.  Just as your class definition gets read by multiple files, but doesn't create multiple implementations.

Comment: Lo and behold, it compiles now. Thanks for the help. Generally, is this common when working on big projects? Do cpp files often cross-reference one another or is that something I should avoid in the future?

Comment: It is common enough in libraries that the functions that work together are spread out and need to know each other's definitions.  For your class, you might want to think about whether it makes sense for those stand along functions to instead be static members of the class.  That's more of an aesthetic call though.

Comment: My gut reaction is these functions should stand on their own. My program is going to want to create numbers based on existing numbers. So I want to say: `bigNumber sum = addNumbers(number1, number2);`. Would I be able to call the `addNumbers()` without an existing object if that function were the member of a class? Instead, would I be forced to make a random object `bigNumber adder;`, then say `bigNumber sum = adder.addNumbers(number1, number2);`?

Comment: A static function in a class does not require a member, so it would work exactly the way you wanted, except that you would have to qualify the class: `bigNumber sum= bigNumber::add(number1, number2) ;`