# How do I create one .exe from 2 saperate .cpp files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a project where I need to call a c++ project from another c++ project. I am trying to create a project which receives data through UDP and with that data calls another program which performs and returns some calculations and then the returned calculation result is transmitted over UDP. The cpp file which performs that calculation also has a main function which makes it impossible to be used as a header file. How do I approach this problem? I cannot edit the program which performs calculation since it is too complicated for me to understand. The UDP code is far easier and hence that will be my main program. How do I create a single solution with 2 separate cpp files with separate main functions? I do not want to use system call to make 2 separate .exe files and calling one after another.

Comment: Rename the main function to something else.

Comment: You will have to understand the code (at least to a small degree) to be able to call it.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis That I understand. I know which parameters to pass and which type to use to pass the parameters. If I use that calculation in the UDP function and change the main function, I know how to call that function. Unfortunately, I am just unable to change or edit the entire code as it is 10,000 line code and I can't understand and I am not allowed to change it either.

Comment: @drescherjm That I understand. I know which parameters to pass and which type to use to pass the parameters. If I use that calculation in the UDP function and change the main function, I know how to call that function. Unfortunately, I am just unable to change or edit the entire code as it is 10,000 line code and I can't understand and I am not allowed to change it either.

Comment: There is not much we can help with in a question like this. There is no general rule. @MichaelChourdakis probably has the correct idea.

Comment: If you are using g++ : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462420/how-do-i-compile-multiple-cpp-files-into-a-single-executable-using-g-when-the